# How to make winform GUI appearance the same in different operating systems?

Tags: c#, winforms

My Winform application is developed using visual studio 2013, and the operating system is windows 8. But when we run the application in windows 7 operating system, the GUI varies (not for all windows 7 machines).But it runs perfectly in windows 10 machines.

What I have tried:

I tried changing the height,padding etc. of controls in all the forms .but it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to set the FlatStyle property of each control ?